# Hiding a State monad's s type parameter

Tags: haskell, existential-type, gadt

I'm trying to hide the type parameter of a `State` monad in a new type, but I'm having a hard time unifying the existentially qualified `s` with the `g` to be provided for `evalFoo`. I've tried with `ExistentialQuantification`, `GADTs`, and `RankNTypes`, but have an admittedly very poor understanding of how these extensions work.

How would the idiomatic Haskell way to accomplish this look?
Thanks!

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import System.Random

data Foo a where
  Foo :: RandomGen s => State s a -> Foo a

evalFoo :: RandomGen g => Foo a -> g -> a
evalFoo (Foo m) g = evalState m g
```

The goal is to achieve something like this, but to able to supply any instance of `RandomGen`:

```
myRNG :: Foo Double
myRNG = Foo $ do
  u <- state random
  return u

Prelude> evalFoo myRNG (mkStdGen 123)
0.7804356004944119
```

Comment: `myRNG = Foo $ state random`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existential quantification in the type of the `Foo` constructor would mean that for every value of type `Foo`, there is some instance of `RandomGen` that it uses as its state. You want the opposite, though: you want that given any value `foo :: Foo`, and **any** instance `g` of `RandomGen`, you can use `g` as the state of the computation encapsulated by `foo`.

So let's write that instead:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import System.Random

newtype Foo a = MkFoo{ unFoo :: forall g. (RandomGen g) => State g a }

evalFoo :: RandomGen g => Foo a -> g -> a
evalFoo = evalState . unFoo
```

This can be used as expected:

```
myRNG :: Foo Double
myRNG = MkFoo $ do
    u <- state random
    return u
```

giving

```
*Main> evalFoo myRNG (mkStdGen 123)
0.43927189736460226
```

Yeah, not quite 0.78 ;)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is pretty much as you describe. You will not be able to unify the existentially wrapped random seed with your initial random seed. The most obvious approach is to drop the existential quantification altogether, and just use this:

```
runRandomly :: RandomGen g => State g a -> g -> a
runRandomly (Foo m) g = evalState m g
```

I don't see any problem with the most obvious approach in this context. If you really want to hide the seed type from the transformer, [Cactus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327506/1477667) shows how to do it correctly.

In some other contexts, some similar existential wrappings can work by wrapping up the seed along with the transformer:

```
data Foo a where
  Foo :: RandomGen s => State s a -> s -> Foo a
```

You can see an example of something similar in the `foldl` package.

Comment: I think there is merit to hiding the choice of `g`, since it forces you to not do anything instance-specific with it.

Comment: @Cactus, what's that win you?

Comment: Well, for one, you can't replace the state, from the inside, with a new random generator pulled out of thin air.

Comment: @Cactus, no, you can't do *that*, but you can reuse old ones as long as you wish, which is just as bad! This does stop you from leaking the generators, but what's the point?

Comment: Depending on what you want, maybe you want to forbid generator reuse, which you can do by exposing only `state random` and a `Monad` instance (i.e. no `MonadState`). But maybe you want to allow generator reuse. It depends on the use case.